Proof assistant comparison chart
Is there a proof assistant comparison chart for common tasks?
I'm picturing something like this very old page comparing SML and OCaml, which I found helpful when I was learning OCaml because it made some of the design decisions more clear. It also has a narrative OCaml is pragmatic, SML tries to keep its spec small.
That page has a good mix of shallow features like the syntax of character literals and deeper ones like the semantics of eqtypes and the module system. This makes Adam Chlipala's page useful even to people who don't know either OCaml or SML.
We have some explicit comparisons between proof assistants on this site already like this one and Coq vs Lean, our highest rated question.
There are also papers out there like The Seventeen Provers of the World that compare proofs of a nontrivial theorem and let's prove leftpad which has many verified implementations of leftpad.
However, there doesn't seem to be anything as accessible as the OCaml vs SML comparison.

Semi-serious: https://jiggerwit.wordpress.com/2018/04/14/the-architecture-of-proof-assistants/ (Lean is out of date, and Agda is missing.)

Coq is built of modular components on a foundation of dependent type theory. This system has grown one PhD thesis at a time. I like it.

I would like to create one, but I would need help from experts of other proof assistants than Mizar
